# window.print not working for firefox

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not that familiar with the JS functions that are not applicable for firefox, thus i i'm posting here to ask you guys on what is wrong with my code. works on any other browsers except firefox.

```
var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
var footstr = "</body>"; 
var newstr = document.all.item("printable").innerHTML; 
var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML; 
document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr; 
window.print(); 
document.body.innerHTML = oldstr; 
return false;
```

I did some reading and all i got was that document.focus is not applicable for firefox, but i'm not using that line of code so i'm a bit lost as to what is causing my problem. thank you all.

what happens is it does nothing at all, tried to do an alert just in case and it worked fine (commented all that code of course and only left the alert).

Comment: What *actually* happens?  Error?  Nothing at all?

Comment: sorry about that, the button cannot be clicked, tried changing the code to do an alert and it worked

Comment: Why don't you use CSS (`@media print`) for this purpose instead of messing around with JavaScript?

Comment: don't use document.all.item. Where from do have that code?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I wasn't aware that such function existed until now. will it be able to print what i have inside a div? But do you have any idea what is wrong with that code above so that i would be able to avoid such problems in the future

Comment: You could hide everything but that div. Have a look at the print preview of this page - it looks pretty different from the regular view.

Comment: @Bergi pardon? what do you mean don't use document.all.item?

Comment: @magicianIam: document.all is outdated and non-standard. Use document.getElementById() or document.getElementsByName()...

Comment: ``document.all`` was deprecated years ago, and no browser is expected to support it. There are other (standard) methods to manipulate the DOM.

Comment: thanks for all the info. already had it running using var newstr = document.getElementById("printable").innerHTML;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox does not print anything, because an early error is thrown. `document.all` is `undefined` in Firefox. Upon opening the console, the following error message should become visible near `var newstr = ...`:

```
TypeError: document.all is undefined
```

Comment: I see, i didn't have firebug installed so i wasnt been able to see that, but firefox does not support document.all.item?

Comment: @magicianIam `document.all` is `undefined`. Obviously, the `item` method does not exists either. FYI: Firefox has a built-in console, press Ctrl+Shift+J.

Comment: i see, thank you for that. Do you have any idea as an alternative for that functionality? thank you

Comment: @magicianIam [`document.getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementsByName) (returns an array-like `NodeList` object) or [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getElementById)

Comment: i just read an article that says DONT USE document.all. lol. i'll try usign document.getElementByID(). thanks

Comment: @magicianIam JavaScript is case-sensitive. Use `document.getElementById()`, with a lowercase `d` in `Id`.

Comment: thanks rob, will try to manipulate my code and find an alternative for document.all.